# How can I log back to Pokemon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

My character was lvl 19 on my account and yesterday when I tapped on the app, it brought me back to the original screen when you first start playing. I signed in which the same google account. Now every time I log in it's starts with the lvl 1 character. What can I do? How can i continue whit my lvl19 account...?

Comment: I heard there was a mess up at Niantic, they accidently reset some accounts. So uhh maybe you have that problem

Answer (score -1):

You should log out and check that it's the same google account that you previously used, someone reported that a number was added to his email adress.